# Difference between @FindBy vs driver.findElement()?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, findby, page-factory

I have used both of them but not know where should I use `@findBy` and where I use `driver.findElement()`

I heard that `@FindBy` behaves dynamically whereas `driver.findElement()` behaves as static. What does this mean?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Selenium WebDriver @FindBy and findElement() difference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35980760/selenium-webdriver-findby-and-findelement-difference)

Answer (score 0):

Both `@FindBy` and `driver.findElement()` are different approach towards achieving the same target i.e. to locate element/s through different [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890).

When using **PageFactory** we can use the [Annotation Type FindBy](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/FindBy.html). The **FindBy** annotations helps us to remove the *boiler-plate* code which we generally use in the form of `findElement()` and `findElements()` when looking for elements.

As an example:

```
WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.name("q"));
element.click();
```

becomes:

```
element.click();
```

You can find @Simon Stewart's comments on the same topic within the discussion [How to use explicit waits with PageFactory fields and the PageObject pattern](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/webdriver/7AGczMaV578)